# How can I determine standard deviation in excel given the probability that values will fall within a defined range?

Tags: standard-deviation, excel

Assuming a normal distribution with a mean of zero, if I am told that 68.2% of the population values are within +/- 4.7, I can conclude that the standard deviation is also 4.7.

But what if I am told instead that 50% of the population values are within +/- 4.7?  How can I determine the standard deviation in excel given this information?

Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ be a centered normal distributed random variable and $Z\sim N(0,1)$ be a standard normal distributed random variable and $\Phi$ its distribution function. For a given $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $c \in (0,1)$ you have, since the density of $Z$ is symmetric around $0$:
\begin{align*}
P(- a\leq X \leq a) & = P\left(-\frac{a}{\sigma} \leq Z \leq \frac{a}{\sigma}\right)\\&= \Phi\left(\frac{a}{\sigma}\right) - \Phi\left(-\frac{a}{\sigma}\right)\\&= 2 \Phi\left(\frac{a}{\sigma}\right)-1 \\& \stackrel{!}{=}c \\
\qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \sigma &  = \frac{a}{\Phi^{-1}((c+1)/2)}.
\end{align*}
Hence, for $a=4.7$ and $c=0.5$ you can derive the value of $\sigma$ by writing
  `4.7/NORM.S.INV(0.75)` in excel, as `NORM.S.INV(prob)` corresponds to $\Phi^{-1} (prob)$.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to set st_dev such that norm.dist(4.7,0,st_dev,True) = 0.75
Coming up with a strategy to solve this should be straightforward, or use trial and error.
(So, for that st_dev, 75% percent of the population values are below 4.7, which means that 25% are below -4.7, so 50% are in between -4.7 and 4.7, as required).